Hosting static web on azure storage
I developed a simple flutter web-app and build the code using flutter build web command, then using a static website, I uploaded the build folder and provided the index.html. Then, I saved and got the primary URL.
But, when I tried to run the website in Chrome or Edge, it outputs the following error:

Also, the blob is in private (no anonymous access). Is it compulsory to keep the blog in anonymous read access. Can't we do it in private access?

You can modify the anonymous access level of the web container but makeing change does effect primary Static endpoint. While primary Static website endpoint isn't affected. Error is web not found may be it has do host a static website on blob storage so follow the steps in link to do so
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website-host

thank you changed the index.html directory it worked
